# Adding 2 controls to 1 data row with Telerik and dynamic data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, telerik

I have to add a data row dynamically to a table and one of the rows uses a text box to display a date and a date icon where a calender shows up.  Normally this is down by hard coding on our asp.net page but the designer of the page I inherited decided to dynamically create all the tables and rows, columns.
The client wants the same function as our hard coded page done in this dynamic table.  My question is:

can you dynamically add 2 controls to one data row that is created dynamically in 1 column?  If so how would one do this?

I need it for the following row

AddGridRow(dt, "Rating Date (252)", "ST_RATG_DA", "ST_RATG_DA_ID", paircode: "-1");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create template columns programmatically: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html#Section4. Take a look at the entire article, especially the beginning to get the basic concepts.